# Print Specific Value from an API Request in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, github

I am trying to print the values from an API Request. The JSON file returned is large(4,000 lines) so I am just trying to get specific values from the key value pair and automate a message.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib


url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<companyName>/<repoName>/issues" #url 

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <masterToken>' #authorization works fine 
}
name = (user.login) #pretty sure nothing is being looked out
url = (url)

print(hello %name, you have a pull request to view. See here %url for more information) # i want to print those keys here
```

The JSON file (exported from the API get request is as followed:

```
[
    {
        **"url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>/issues/1000",**
        "repository_url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>",
        "labels_url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>/issues/1000labels{/name}",
        "comments_url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>/issues/1000",
        "events_url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>/issues/1000",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/<ompanyName>/<repo>/issues/1000",
        "id": <id>,
        "node_id": "<nodeID>",
        "number": 702,
        "title": "<titleName>",
        "user": {
            **"login": "<userName>",**
            "id": <idNumber>,
            "node_id": "nodeID",
            "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/urlName?v=4",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>",
            "html_url": "https://github.com/<userName>",
            "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/followers",
            "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/following{/other_user}",
            "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/gists{/gist_id}",
            "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
            "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/subscriptions",
            "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/orgs",
            "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/repos",
            "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/events{/privacy}",
            "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/<userName>/received_events",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": false
        },
]
```

(note this JSON file repeats a few hundred times)
From the API request, I am trying to get the nested "login" and the url. 
What am I missing? 
Thanks

Edit:

Solved:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib


url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<companyName>/<repoName>/issues"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <masterToken>'
}

response = requests.get(url).json()
for obj in response:
    name = obj['user']['login']
    url = obj['url']
    print('Hello {0}, you have an outstanding ticket to review. For more information see here:{1}.'.format(name,url))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a JSON array you have to loop over it. And JSON objects are converted to dictionaries, so you use `['key']` to access the elements.

```
for obj in response:
    name = obj['user']['login']
    url = obj['url']
    print(f'hello {name}, you have a pull request to view. See here {url} for more information')
```

Comment: Thank you. I slightly modified that but it totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse it into a python lists/dictionaries and then access it like any other python object.

```py
response = requests.get(...).json()

login = response[0]['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON formatted data to a Python dictionary like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

```
json_data = ... # response from API
dict_data = json.loads(json_data)

login = response[0]['user']['login']
url = response[0]['url']
```